# null returned intead of 0 on sum when not data in table laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

**My query**

```
 $summary['total_cash'] = DB::table('wallets')
                                  ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_cash'))
                                  ->where('payment_details','affiliate product purchase commission')
                                  ->where('user_id',$group_id)
                                  ->first()->total_cash;
```

error I get
https://prnt.sc/sjllwv

there is no data available in any of these tables

I want to return 0

please forget if any typo error

Thank You

Comment: Please show what you want returned.  Your query returns multiple columns so `0` does not make sense.  I think you should really handle this in the application.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code and error you've posted

Comment: @iainn , query edited, please look at this now

Comment: `where('payment_details','affiliate product purchase commission')` is wrong. Does `payment_details` must have one of this 4 values? if so use `whereIn` method.

Comment: do you have null by default in your database table ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yes, but i have changed to 0

Comment: If you just only to change `amount` to `0` then below answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are having amount field NULL by default in your database, then try this**

```
$summary['total_cash'] = DB::table('wallets')
                         ->select(DB::raw('coalesce(SUM(amount),0) as total_cash'))
                         ->where('payment_details','affiliate product purchase commission')
                         ->where('user_id',$group_id)
                         ->first()->total_cash
```